# Dialogs in OpenAI

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model

Afaik, there're two ways of interacting with text OpenAI api now: completions and chat.
I want to build this:

1. Application receives messages from user1 and user2 and sends messages to OpenAI like it's a dialog.
2. OpenAI just listens and only replies if it sees some pattern in the conversation.

Is it possible to achieve somehow? Thank you.

Comment: You would probably have to ask OpenAI a question with each interaction and ask it to answer with something predetermined that you ignore if the pattern is not detected. Such as "Does this conversation so signs of XYZ?" If not reply simply with "No" and then don't show anything if you see "No" as the response. But you likely need some Fine Tuning

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Chat interface. You can't set roles for multiple users yet, but send the model something like this:

```py
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "Say something if you detect a pattern in the user messages. Otherwise say nothing."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "User1: I'm in charge."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "User2: I'mway inway hargecay."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "User1: stop repeating me"},
    {"role": "user", "content": "User2: opstay epeatingray emay."}
  ]
)
print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```

```
% python foo.py
User1 and User2 are both speaking in Pig Latin.
```